# Tension in a stone, string system undergoing uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string, centripetal-force

I've recently read that a string can be assumed to be a spring with a really high spring constant, and it applies a force in the opposite direction to the force being applied [image]
Like in this case, notice how the weights and the tensions of m1 and m3 are in the opposite directions. Now i look at a picture of a stone tied to string undergoing uniform circular motion [image]

and i didn't really see anything pulling the ball away from the center of the cirle for the tension to act towards the center of the circle. Clearly i went wrong somewhere, any help would really be appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Comment: As other answers below have hinted at, there actually is not force pulling the ball outwards (at least if you are in an inertial reference frame ).

Comment: In order to keep the ball traveling in a circle, you need to continually change the direction of its velocity vector.  The translates into an acceleration toward the center of the circle.  You need tension in the string to bring about this radial acceleration inward.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to find another force initially.  Look for some motion or possible motion which would cause the string to stretch if it could. In the circular motion situation, the mass would normally move in a straight line, which means the string would need to stretch. Because the string in *not* stretching, you know there must be a tension force in the string.  Strings can only pull, so the tension force must be away from the mass. And the tension force of a flexible string must be co-linear with the string.

Consequently, the string pulls on the mass toward the center of the circle (ideally) if the speed is constant. According to Newton's 3rd Law, the mass pulls outward on the string and that keeps the string accelerating with the mass.

Answer (score 1):

Without the tension, the ball will fly off at a tangent. The answer to your question lies almost entirely in Newton's First Law. The ball is always attempting to fly off in a straight line (which will elongate the string), but the string is holding it back (by modelling it as a rigid spring, as you mentioned). The velocity and the tension are perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 0):

> and i didn't really see anything pulling the ball away from the center of the cirle for the tension to act towards the center of the circle

Why would there be?

It seems you assume forces to always be balanced. That is definitely not the case. You can punch me in the face with a force, and my face flies backwards. Nothing balances out your punching force - which is the reason that my face accelerates away.

Or think of a bat hitting a baseball. No force balances out the hitting force from the bat. And of that reason the net force is free to cause large acceleration of the ball. If you hit a wall, the wall would produce a large enough normal force to balance it out, and the net force would be zero. Therefor the wall doesn't move.

- In your examples with masses, they aren't acceleration - meaning, the net force on them is zero - meaning, the tension forces are balanced out (by gravity in these cases).
- In your ball-in-a-string example, there **is** acceleration. It points inwards towards the centre. That acceleration - called *centripetal* acceleration - is what causes the ball to constantly turn and curve around the centre. There must be non-zero net force on the ball; otherwise there would be no such acceleration inwards. So there must be a non-balanced force.

And that is the string tension. It constantly pulls inwards and causes the acceleration to always be present.

---

These two situations are Newton's 1st and 2nd laws. The 1st law is the no-acceleration case which implies fully balanced forces (the sum up to zero):

$$\sum F=0$$

while the 2nd law is the acceleration case which implies *non*-balanced forces (they don't sum up to zero - in fact, they sum up to cause the acceleration):

$$\sum F=ma$$

In general, if you have a force and think you are another, then try to consider if the object is in fact accelerating. If so, then there may not be another force.

Comment: This is probably the third time I have seen an answer on physics SE that mentions someone getting punched in the face. Is this you each time or someone else? :)

Comment: @AaronStevens Uh, I love that example. A practical and Earth-bound try-this-at-home example that we can all relate to.